# What is the origin of "bouillon cubes"?

Tags: word-choice, etymology

What is the etymology of *bouillon cubes*? What other word can I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Wiktionary page for *bouillon*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bouillon) describes the etymology well. The immediate origin of the word is quite clearly French, and is cognate with *boil* in English.

> First attested 1656, from French
>   bouillir (“to boil”), from Old French
>   boillir, from Latin bullīre, present
>   active infinitive of bulliō (“I
>   bubble, boil”), from bulla (“bubble”).

A *bouillon cube* is simply a bit of dehydrated bullion (broth) shaped into a cube, so it can be easily added to a liquid to quickly season a broth.

(Why do I feel I'm on the Food and Cooking StackExchange site..?)

Comment: The answer doesn't explain why a word that means _I boil_ is then used to mean _broth_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: It's pretty obvious... one boils a liquid/vegetable/meat mixture in the process of making a broth.

Comment: It seems like there is a missing step. For example, in Italian _bollito_ refers to boiled meat, but _bouillon cube_ is translated in _dado per brodo_ (literally, "cube for broth"). Even if _bouillon_ would be the French word for _boiled_, understanding why _bouillon cube_ is used is not immediate.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I'm not sure where you feel there's a missing step. Etymology (or linguistics) is no exact science, but I see the progression well enough. (Perhaps the strangeness stems from English not being native to you?)

Comment: The missing part is that _bouillon_ literally means "liquid in which something has boiled."

Comment: Well that could have been a meaning at some point, yes. English is a very liberal language, even semantically. I can imagine this takes some getting used to. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard another word to describe a bouillon cube, but there are at least three of words for the *product* of a bouillon cube. Stock, Broth, Soup.

Comment: As the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouillon_cube) points out, bouillon cubes are commonly known in the UK and some commonwealth countries as *stock cubes*.

Comment: @PLL: Yes, definitely - I didn't know what a bouillon cube was (though I probably would have guessed correctly) - they're only known as "stock cubes" in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

If you said "broth cube", people would look at you funny, but they'd probably know what you meant.